# Turn off automatic display of properties

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In my workplace, any time I open an Excel sheet (Office Professional Plus 2010) the "Document Properties" or "Other Properties - Server" docked dialog appears at the top of the document, dominating a lot of real estate. How can I turn this off so that it does not automatically appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the Developer ribbon > Document Panel and untick "Always show Document Information panel on document open and initial save".

[image]

(If you don't see the Developer ribbon, you need to enable it first via Right-Click on any ribbon > Customize the Ribbon > tick "Developer" in the list of ribbons on the right.)

Comment: That's great. The tickbox is greyed out though. I guess they want us to see it all the time..

Comment: I think this setting can be forced from Sharepoint or other server locations to ensure that metadata is in the user's face and filled in.